# How to connect 2 WiFi routers to a modem via a switch

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have a large(ish) house, and I have a WiFi router set up in the place where it gets signal to as much of the house as it can, however there are 2 rooms to the side of it where there is no internet access. The router I have at the moment is the Plusnet Hub One, which provides internet to most of the house, and I also have another Plusnet WiFi router (tg582n) which I would like to connect to the internet alongside the main router, in order to provide WIFI to the rest of the house.

My current setup is as follows:

```
BT openreach modem --> TPLink 5 port switch --> Plusnet Hub One

                                            --> Plusnet tg582n
```

This seems to allow me to connect only 1 router at a time to the internet, despite having both plugged into the switch.

Does anyone know how I could connect both of these to the internet at the same time?

Comment: Unfortunately, the configuration of routers and WiFi access points is something device-specific, so you'll have more luck on the manufacturer's support website/forums. That being said, have considered using a WiFi repeater? It is a device that picks up weak WiFi signals and amplify them.

Comment: By the way, could you describe what the problem actually looks like? i.e. error messages & such being shown on the devices that try to connect to the second router? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried repeaters, but the ones I've found either seem to come unpaired quickly(if connected wirelessly) or don't connect, if connected wire wires, as the 2 aforementioned rooms are on a different fuse box, so the signal can't get through, and I'd rather not get another one purely because I bought a few, and I'd rather not spend any more money on it, and I had a spare router lying around that didn't have a use

Comment: There router that isn't connecting ( tg582n) has all the lights solidly on, with the occasional flicker, except the internet light, which is off. When a device connects to the router, it says "connected, no internet", "sign into network" or "connected with problems". This router is capable of connecting to the Internet, as that was my main router for over year, and I tested it the other day, and got the internet on it, but forst I had to disconnect the other router to use the socket.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of connecting two routers to the modem, it would probably work better to configure one of the routers as an access point and joining them on the LAN. This is device-specific, but usually involves turning off DHCP and hooking the access point to the *LAN* ports on the main router. (The connection is on the LAN side.) [Here's a generic description](http://www.tested.com/tech/298-how-to-use-an-old-router-to-expand-your-wi-fi-network/). I've done this myself with routers that don't have official support for running in AP mode.

This way, one router takes care of all the routing while the second router takes care only of WIFI.

Comment: I've looked into this before, but I couldn't find a way of disabling DHCP on the router, or changing the router's IP address (they both use 192.168.1.254)

Comment: I found [these instructions](https://www.spark.co.nz/help/internet-data/equipment/technicolour/technicolor-tg582n-help-and-support/change-lan-settings-technicolor-modems/) for changing the IP address. Not sure about the DHCP server though. That router, however, doesn't look like the best candidate for a wifi AP (Amazon reviews cite poor wireless performance). You might want to consider buying a newer, cheaper router off Amazon.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I'm thinking of buying a new router, as both of these were free from Plusnet, but I figured it would be cheaper for try and get this working rather than buying a new on straight away

Comment: Linked pages no longer found. 404.